# Elasticsearch replica shard

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup a replica shard on a second node, and I tried the codes on es website without any success. So, how could I modify the config file on both es instances? All help is much appreciated.

FYI, here is what I want to setup:

1. ES1: primary node for index A
2. ES2: backup node for index A

In case ES1 fails, ES2 should still be available. I should maybe curl [ip]:9200/index/type and still be able to access the data.

Comment: There is no primary and backup node. You have primary shard (a piece of an index) and a replica shard (a copy of the same piece of index).

Comment: add your log files for es cluster from the log folder in $ES_HOME